# Attempt to upgrade vmtools within a Windows Server 2008 Server VM Causes vm to become extremely unstable

Tags: ethernet

I run Ubuntu 14.04 upgraded from 12.04 after the upgrade I had to get patches to get the new kernel to run my virtual machines (vmware workstation 9).

After failing to figure out the virtual network module and the vmci, I just downloaded and installed Workstation 10. Then upgraded my vms to Workstation 10 compatibilty, without making any clones.

Two things are now going crazy: permissions keep jumping to root, on the vmdk files in one of the VMs.
Secondly, when the VM starts, the network is goofy, and "vmware tools is outdated" message came. I tried to update  and it literally became super unstable. This vm is a Windows 2008 Ent server that runs the office.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it all. The reason the vm was unresponsive was that simply the upgrade took a long time. Secondly, I had lost my dns and dhcp scope due to the length of time offline and had to recover it from dns backup. If someone has that latter problem, I used the following resource....https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc774607(v=ws.10).aspx

Best.